# On what mysqlnd version utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci introduced?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf8mb4

I'm aware that:

- utf8mb4 require Mysql 5.5.3+ or Mysqlnd 5.0.9+
- utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci require Mysql 5.6+

I have Mysqlnd 5.0.12 and it's support utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci.

I'm curious to know on what Mysqlnd version is utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci introduced?

was it along with v5.0.9? if not, what version is require to use unicode_520_ci?

**Update**

- utf8mb4 [added](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/277c7d4deaba3a4c842b479558ecb1971610ed07#diff-0f3710d9187fe2d11ba1024c0b6da1bbR442) to mysqlnd on August, 2010. Possibly released in 5.0.9
- utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci [added](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/f826ea093f8317dda2e5476db128dc5ad3eba442#diff-0f3710d9187fe2d11ba1024c0b6da1bbR643) as new charset on June, 2012. Possibly included in release 5.0.10?

Comment: I suspect that Mysqlnd does not care about collations.  Do you have reason to believe that it does?

Comment: Interesting question, I never considered it before. If I remember correctly there is something called collation_connection; which make me think that  both server and client connection must support same charset and collation in order to work correctly.

Comment: (I don't know the answer.)  The charset controls the encoding; the collation controls ordering and comparing strings.  I can't imaging that the driver would be worrying about ordering or comparing.  But, as you point out, it may need to _set_ collation_connection.  What version of _PHP_ are you using?

Comment: I use PHP 7.1.8 had no issue with the collation, my question is purely curiosity